# Change product key by reinstalling Sharepoint

Tags: licence

If I reinstall Sharepoint, can I change product key for new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, make sure you uninstall all language pack then run the SharePoint uninstaller (also from control panel > program and features) and remove the leftover databases. You can then start from scratch (well, nearly, since all prerequesites will be there)  and provide a new key.